# Debian apt: is there a single command to install and mark as auto?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

Sometimes it is useful to install an optional dependency in the following way:

```
apt-get install foo
apt-mark auto foo
```

Is there a single apt command to do it in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look possible. Does this count as one command?

```
apt-get install foo && apt-mark auto foo
```

You could create an alias 'aptauto' to do this.